# Third party Error While building project in cocos2dX

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am getting the below error when I am trying to build the cocos2dX code.

> ./build_native.sh NDK_ROOT = /Users/Marine/Documents/android-ndk-r10e
>   COCOS2DX_ROOT = /Users/Marine/Documents/Cocos2dXReq/cocos2d-x-2.2.6
>   APP_ROOT =
>   /Volumes/Data/NewData/Projects/SpikesProj/SourceCode/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DTS/proj.android/..
>   APP_ANDROID_ROOT =
>   /Volumes/Data/NewData/Projects/SpikesProj/SourceCode/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DTS/proj.android
>   marine Using prebuilt externals c=>
>   ./Users/Marine/Documents/Cocos2dXReq/cocos2d-x-2.2.6 Android NDK:
>   WARNING:/Users/Marine/Documents/Cocos2dXReq/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static:
>   LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries     make: Entering
>   directory
>   `/Volumes/Data/NewData/Projects/SpikesProj/SourceCode/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DTS/proj.android'
>   [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= main.cpp [armeabi]
>   Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= AppDelegate.cpp [armeabi]
>   Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= HelloWorldScene.cpp
>   jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp: In member function 'void
>   HelloWorld::checkAch()': jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:873:62:
>   warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
>   [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.10", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:877:62: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.20", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:881:62: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.30", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:885:62: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.40", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:889:62: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.50", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:893:62: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.60", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:897:62: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.70", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:901:62: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.80", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:905:62: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.90", 100);
>                                                                 ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:909:63: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.100", 100);
>                                                                  ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:913:63: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.150", 100);
>                                                                  ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:917:63: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.id.200", 100);
>                                                                  ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:922:65: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.played.5", 100);
>                                                                    ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:926:65: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.played.5", 100);
>                                                                    ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:930:65: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.played.5", 100);
>                                                                    ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:934:65: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.played.5", 100);
>                                                                    ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:938:65: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.played.5", 100);
>                                                                    ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:942:65: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.played.5", 100);
>                                                                    ^ jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:946:65: warning: deprecated
>   conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
>
>   ThirdPartyInterface::reportAchievement("com.ach.played.5", 100);
>                                                                    ^ [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <=
>   ThirdPartyInterface.cpp [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared
>   <= CollisionDetection.cpp [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared
>   <= Shared.cpp [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <=
>   JNIHelpers.cpp [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <=
>   NativeUtils.cpp make: *** No rule to make target`
>   /Users/Bilalmirza/Documents/Developer-Tools/cocos2d-x-2.2.3/extensions/AssetsManager/AssetsManager.cpp',
>   needed by
>   `obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos_extension_static/AssetsManager/AssetsManager.o'.
>   Stop. make: Leaving directory`
>   /Volumes/Data/NewData/Projects/SpikesProj/SourceCode/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DTS/proj.android'
>   Mac-mini:proj.android Marine$ ant debug install Buildfile:
>   /Volumes/Data/NewData/Projects/SpikesProj/SourceCode/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DTS/proj.android/build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED

[Error Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndmmwvxh3oe03vk/buildError.rtf?dl=0)

As I am newbie to cocos2D-x Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you use ndk10. It's adviced to use ndk9 with cocos2d-x. Give it a try.

Comment: Sure! Let me work on the same and then get back to you